# get data from ngrx selector

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

I try to get data from ngrx selector as array using this code

> `categorys$ = this.store.select(getCategorysSelector)`

but I just can get an object of store and I print the result in console and get this :

```
Store {actionsObserver: ActionsSubject, reducerManager: ReducerManager, source: Store, operator: ƒ}
```

hint : my data should be like this

```
1: {_id: '6294cbf9cdd093df47a24d01', name: 'asdasdasd', __v: 0} 2: {_id: '629730d1527c83ae22bc8c62', name: 'asdasd', __v: 0} 3: {_id: '6297311a527c83ae22bc8c65', name: 'asdasd', __v: 0} 4: {_id: '62973120527c83ae22bc8c67', name: 'asdasd', __v: 0}
```

so how i can get my data as array ???

Answer (score 2):

`categorys$ = this.store.select(getCategorysSelector)`

will assign the `Observable` you receive from the selector to your `categorys$` variable.

In order to actually access the data within that selector you need to consume the Observable, either by subscribing to it via the `async` pipe  (https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) in your html code

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let category of categorys$ | async">
  ... do something here
</ng-container>
```

or by explicitly subscribing to your Observable within your ts code:

```
const categorySubscription = this.categorys$.subscribe(categories => {
  // do something here
});
```

In case you directly subscribe in typescript, make sure to unsubscribe from your subscription `OnDestroy`.

Answer (score 0):

```
   this.store.subscribe(state=>{
  this.getValue(state)
  })
}



getValue(value:any){
    this.permission = value.user.permission}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?